# Save one to many without creating

Tags: laravel, one-to-many

I just have a little problem. I have a one to many relationship. A team has many users. Many users have a team.
I have six teams of which the user has to choose one. How can I connect the team with the user without creating a new entry in the database 'team'?

User:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('team_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('username')->nullable()->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('phone')->nullable()->unique();
        $table->string('avatar');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->date('birthday');
        $table->boolean('gender');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Team:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->string('image_thumbnail');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
    public function storeTeam($request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $team = Team::findOrFail($request->team_id);
    $user->team()->associate($team);

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', lang::get('messages.team'));
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<form method="POST" action="{{ URL::route('store.team') }}">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
    <ul class="row clients-dotted list-inline text-center">
      @foreach ($teams as $team)
      <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-6">
        <div class="cc-selector">
          <input id="team{{$team->id}}" type="radio" name="team" value="{{$team->id}}" />
          <label style="background-image:url({{ $team->image_thumbnail }});" class="team-cc" for="team{{$team->id}}"></label>
          <p>{{$team->name}}</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  <button type="submit" class="mb-50 float-right mr-20 btn btn-shadow-1 btn-primary">weiter</button>
</form>
```

route:

```
Route::post('/welcome/team', 'ProfilesController@storeTeam')->name('store.team');
```

i have a little problem with this and get the error:
Type error:

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::storeTeam(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're storing the `team_id` on the `user model`, you can use the `associate` method to set the primary key on the child -- `user` in this case

```
$user->team()->associate($team);
```

You would pass the selected `team` to the controller. Doesn't matter how. You can pass it as part of a route, or you can pass the team ID from a form and get it from the `request`.

You're expecting a variable to literally be passed to the controller called `$request`. What you want is to inject `$request` as a dependency. You can do that by typehinting the resolved variable like so:

```
public function storeTeam(Request $request)
```

Mind you, you'll need to have `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your file, otherwise you will get errors regarding the `Request` class.

Comment: How can I use the code in a function in the controller?

Comment: @slickness Updated.

Comment: @slickness I've updated my question. This is kind off of topic because it's more about how `Dependency Injection` works than anything. Please consider accepting my answer (by clicking the checkmark) if I've helped you. If you have further questions, please make a new question